# Error in seq.default(a, b, by = h) : 'to' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite

Tags: r

I have a two functions one is to calculate the integration and another one is  fixed-point method to find the root.This is the function to calculate the integration:

```
trapezoid <- function(fun, a, b, n=100) {
  h <- (b-a)/n
  x <- seq(a, b, by=h)
  y <- fun(x)
  s <- h * (y[1]/2 + sum(y[2:n]) + y[n+1]/2)
  return(s)
}
```

And this is the root finding function:

```
fixedpoint <- function(fun, x0, tol=1e-03, niter=5000){
  ## fixed-point algorithm to find x such that fun(x) == x
  ## assume that fun is a function of a single variable
  ## x0 is the initial guess at the fixed point
  xold <- x0
  xnew <- fun(xold)
  for (i in 1:niter) {
    xold <- xnew
    xnew <- fun(xold)
    if ( abs((xnew-xold)) < tol )
      return(xnew)
  }
  stop("exceeded allowed number of iterations")
}
```

Now I define a function f `f<-function(x) {x^2}`

And get its integration function  `h<-function(x) trapezoid(f,2,x)`

Last I want to find the roots of h by doing`fixedpoint(h,2)`

But I got the error message like this:

> Error in seq.default(a, b, by = h) : 'to' cannot be NA, NaN or
>   infinite

Comment: what is `simpson()`? do you mean trapezoid?

Comment: Error message is clear, try `seq(1, NA, 1)`, your post is not.

Comment: @vdep sorry, is trapezoid

Comment: @zx8754 how to do this?

Comment: I didn't check your functions in detail, but to avoid error message introduce some kind of check if the values for seq() function are not NA, NaN, Inf.

Comment: In `fixedpoint(h, 2)`, you run `h(xold)` with `xold = 2`. Therefore, you will evaluate `trapezoid(f, 2, 2)`. In `trapezoid()`, `h = 0` and thus `x = 2` and `y = 4`. Since `y` has length one, `y[2:n]` will fail and `s` is `NA`. Later, you will then evaluate `trapezoid(f, 2, NA)` and thus `seq(2, NA, NA)`, which gives you the error.